# Twitter API v2 - Rate Limit

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm accessing Twitter's API v2 and have Academic Research access.
I am interested in pulling as much data as possible, but am getting rate limited.

I am using tweepy in Python to extract the data, and the call "search_all_tweets"
I am looping the extraction for each day and limiting tweets extracted per day. By using time.sleep() I can modify how many tweets I can extract per 15 minutes.

Twitter has published this to answer my question, however I am still in doubt which category and thereby limit I am under:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits#v2-limits

Can anybody help to clarify how many tweets I can extract per 15 minutes before getting rate limited?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Twitter developper portal](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/), select your app in your project and, at the bottom of the Settings tab, check if you have activated the Read and Write permissions in the OAuth 1.0a authentication. If not, activate them and regenerate your tokens.